# Why does closing stdin file descriptor give not running on RPi error?

Tags: python, c++, linux, raspberry-pi, rfcomm

I am making an application where a Raspberry Pi reads serial data from the /dev/rfcomm0 file. I have created a daemon to listen for incoming RFCOMM connections and launch the Python program responsible for reading the incoming serial data with execvp call. Upon daemon initialization, I close stdin, stdout, and stderr in accordance with the daemon tutorial I found on http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html. Essentially this link says to do the following:

1. Fork off the parent process.
2. Change file mode mask (umask)
3. Open any logs for writing.
4. Create a unique Session ID (SID)
5. Change the current working directory to a safe place.
6. Close standard file descriptors.
7. Enter actual daemon code.

My daemon will not work unless I remove `close(STDIN_FILENO)` from my code. If I do not remove that code, I get the following error and I do not know how to fix it.

```
File "/home/BluetoothProject/RFCOMMOut.py", line 7, in <module>
gpio.setup(led_pin, gpio.OUT)
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!
```

Note: I was able to print my error by removing `close(STDERR_FILNO)`

Comment: do you run it under root account?

Comment: I do. All necessary files are also owned by root